# C# Properties, Why check for equality before assignment

Tags: c#, properties

Why do I see people implement properties like this? 
What is the point of checking if the value is equal to the current value?

```
public double? Price
{
    get
    {
        return _price;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_price == value)
            return;
        _price = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: lol - R# says "redundant check before assignment"

Comment: my resharper is not complaining ...

Comment: ah, I'd written it as `if(field != value) field = value;` - it doesn't affect the timings, note - but indeed, R# doesn't spot it with the `if(field == value) return; field = value;` approach

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this case it would be moot; however, in the case where there is an associated side-effect (typically an event), it avoids trivial events. For example:

```
set
{
    if (_price == value)
        return;
    _price = value;
    OnPriceChanged(); // invokes the Price event
}
```

Now, if we do:

```
foo.Price = 16;
foo.Price = 16;
foo.Price = 16;
foo.Price = 16;
```

we don't get 4 events; we get at most 1 (maybe 0 if it is already 16).

In more complex examples there could be validation, pre-change actions *and* post-change actions. All of these can be avoided if you know that it isn't actually a change.

```
set
{
    if (_price == value)
        return;
    if(value < 0 || value > MaxPrice) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    OnPriceChanging();
    _price = value;
    OnPriceChanged();
}
```

Comment: yeah, i was thinking its pointless if its straight forward assignment

Comment: A quick test with pure assignment using Stopwatch for timing shows the check actually makes it twice as slow, but still an extremely small amount of time. Even with 1 million iterations the time taken is .05 seconds.

Comment: The only place I do this is as Marc suggests. I want to fire an event (or carry out some other additional processing) if the value changes but not if it remains the same

Comment: Marc, i am sorry i was wrong about performance of comparing vs assigment. But again, your not directly answering the OP qs. I mean, yes its true about what said on events raising if values are different. But taking the OP's core code, how you would explain why it is done?

Comment: @zenwalker IMO, it is being done out of *habit*, or due to looking at generated code (i.e. in a .designer.cs) and seeing the pattern but missing the context. As presented, it adds no value whatsoever (but does add overhead). So essentially, my answer to this *question* is simply the first 7 words of my answer: "In this case it would be moot.".

Comment: Why is this preferable to `if (_price != value) { _price=value; OnPriceChanged()}` ? Why test just to return?

Comment: @KeithTyler ultimately it doesn't matter - it is a stylistic question; pick whichever you like; they do the same thing

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer, more: it is an evidence-based response to the claim (in another answer) that it is quicker to check than to assign. In short: no, it isn't. No difference *whatsoever*. I get (for non-nullable `int`):

```
AutoProp: 356ms
Field: 356ms
BasicProp: 357ms
CheckedProp: 356ms
```

(with some small variations on successive runs - but essentially they all take exactly the same time within any sensible rounding - when doing something 500 MILLION times, we can ignore 1ms difference)

In fact, if we change to `int?` I get:

```
AutoProp: 714ms
Field: 536ms
BasicProp: 714ms
CheckedProp: 2323ms
```

or `double?` (like in the question):

```
AutoProp: 535ms
Field: 535ms
BasicProp: 539ms
CheckedProp: 3035ms
```

so this is ***not*** a performance helper!

with tests

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Test();
        Stopwatch watch;
        const int LOOP = 500000000;
        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
        {
            obj.AutoProp = 17;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("AutoProp: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
        {
            obj.Field = 17;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
        {
            obj.BasicProp = 17;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("BasicProp: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
        {
            obj.CheckedProp = 17;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("CheckedProp: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public int AutoProp { get; set; }
    public int Field;

    private int basicProp;
    public int BasicProp
    {
        get { return basicProp; }
        set { basicProp = value; }
    }

    private int checkedProp;
    public int CheckedProp
    {
        get { return checkedProp; }
        set { if (value != checkedProp) checkedProp = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: weird. I compared BasicProp & CheckedProp and it gave a longer time for CheckedProp. Just out of curiosity are you running a 64 bit system?

Comment: @markoo yes, win-7, x64, i7 CPU. BTW, I added timings for a few different data types, too

Comment: Aaah, that was it. The nullable, which I tested first. Interesting.

Comment: @markoo yeah, "lifted operators" have a bit more overhead; it is more noticeable in this case simply because `int` and `double` have direct IL equality implementations; in cases like `DateTime` or `decimal` it would be less noticeable.

Comment: Good to know. As an extra note: your check for != is also a lot faster than checking == and then returning.

Comment: @markoo that's odd - there's no reason it should be; it is still either brtrue_s or brfalse_s

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we don't handle any change related events.
I don't think comparing is faster than assingment. It depends on the data type. Let's say you have a string, Comparison is much longer in the worst case than a simple assignment where the member simply changes reference to the ref of the new string.
So my guess is that it's better in that case to assign right away.
In the case of simple data types it doesn't have a real impact.

Answer (score -1):

Such that, you dont have to re-assign the same value. Its just faster execution for comparing values. AFAIK

Comment: Comparing is faster than assigment. Say if its a big datastructure and its memory has to be created again and again (ref type) or if its not been instantiated for the first time, then exception is thrown.

Comment: if this is true, does this imply that we should avoid using the auto property?

Comment: I see no evidence in this claim whatsoever. See the test I added for a demonstration.

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. Thanks for taking away my sweat earned points ;)